# Syntaxe error source with QSqlQuery

Tags: c++, mysql, database, qt, qsqlquery

I have a problem with a QSqlQuery when I execute a source command on my database.
This code works :

```
QString myRequest = "CREATE DATABASE MY_DATABASE;";
lQueryResult.Exec(myRequest);
if(!lQueryResult.GetMexec())
{
    qDebug() << "Error in the request";
    return false;
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "The request is OK";
}
```

This code doesn't works, I have a syntax error :

> You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
>   server version for the right syntax to use near 'source
>   ./folder/myFile.sql' at line 1 QMYSQL: Unable to execute query

This is the code :

```
myRequest = "source myFile.sql";
lQueryResult.Exec(myRequest);
if(!lQueryResult.GetMexec())
{
    qDebug() << "Error";
    qDebug() << lQueryResult.LastError();
    return false;
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "OK";
}
```

I can successfully do my source with this command :

```
QString lCommand("mysql -uUsername -pPassword Data_Base -e \"source " + variablePath + variableFile + ".sql\"");
        system(lCommandeProvisoire.toStdString().c_str());
```

I have no error. But, if I execute this code juste after, I have the error

> No database selected QMYSQL: Unable to execute query

:

```
TheRequest = "SELECT * FROM MyTable;";
        QueryResult.Exec(TheRequest);
        if(!QueryResult.GetMexec())
        {
            qDebug() << QueryResult.LastError();
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "OK";
        }
```

But, If I execute a select * from MyTable in shell, it works.

Also, if I execute this in a shell logged in mysql, it works :

```
source myFile.sql
```

Comment: And which error is in  `lQueryResult.LastError()` ?

Comment: Juste updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SOURCE` is [MySQL client command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html) which means it is executed by MySQL shell, not by MySQL server, so you can't execute it via `QSqlQuery`. You can work around this by reading whole file and then sending it's contents to server.

Comment: OK ! There is a mean to backup my database with .sql dump by executing a command wich return a QSqlQuery ? And why if I do a select after the source command my tables are not ready ? But If I do in shell it's ok.

Comment: As I wrote: Instead of executing `SOURCE`, read commands from that file and execute them directly.